# contentOffset of UIScrollView during rotation

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, rotation

I want to manually update the `contentOffset` of an `UIScrollView` during rotation changes. The scroll view fills the screen and has flexible width and flexible height.

I'm currently trying to update the contentOffset in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, like this:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [Utils logPoint:myScrollView.contentOffset tag:@"initial"];
    myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(modifiedX, modifiedY);
    [Utils logPoint:myScrollView.contentOffset tag:@"modified"];
}

-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [Utils logPoint:myScrollView.contentOffset tag:@"final"];
}
```

However, the final value is not the modified value, and it kinda seems to be influenced by it, but it's not evident to me how.

These are some of the results that I get:

```
initial: (146.000000;-266.000000)
modified: (81.000000;-108.000000)
final: (59.000000;-0.000000)

initial: (146.000000;-266.000000)
modified: (500.000000;500.000000)
final: (59.000000;500.000000)

initial: (146.000000;-266.000000)
modified: (-500.000000;-500.000000)
final: (-0.000000;-0.000000)
```

How do I update the contentOffset of a scroll view during a rotation change?

Comment: Did you try changing the contentOffset in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` instead? An animation block should be in place by then, maybe the outcome is different.

Comment: @Pascal Yes, and It works fine. Still I'd like to know why it doesn't behave as expected if I change it in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: My guess would be that the frame of the parent only changes **after** `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, so you set a different contentOffset, but that one is changed immediately again because the superview's frame also only changes then. For the OS it's like you would have changed the frame some time earlier, not with respect to the pending rotation.

Comment: @Pascal Would you mind posting your comments as an answer? I think they're useful and deserve upvotes.

Comment: Good idea. It's not that I don't want those points... ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer :)

Try changing `contentOffset` from within `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` instead. An animation block should be in place by then, and the OS regards your changes to contentOffset as belonging to the changes caused by the rotation.

If you change contentOffset before, it looks like the system doesn't respect these changes as belonging to the rotation, and still applies rotation-resizing, this time starting from your new dimensions.

Comment: Worked like a charm, adding code snippets to help others out.

Comment: this method is deprecated. Try using `viewWillTransitionToSize` or `willTransitionToTraitCollection`

Answer (score 4):

Following snippets does the trick when paging is enabled on UIScrollView and page offset is to be maintained.

Declare a property which will calculate position of currentPage before rotation, and set it to -1 in `viewDidLoad`

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger lastPageBeforeRotate;
```

Then override the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation:duration` method and assign calculated value to it.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    int pageWidth = self.scrollView.contentSize.width / self.images.count;
    int scrolledX = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    self.lastPageBeforeRotate = 0;

    if (pageWidth > 0) {
        self.lastPageBeforeRotate = scrolledX / pageWidth;
    }

    [self showBackButton:NO];
}
```

Then we ensure that before rotation is performed, we set our scrollview's content offset correctly, so as to focus it to our `lastPageBeforeRotate`

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
        if (self.lastPageBeforeRotate != -1) {
            self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * self.lastPageBeforeRotate, 0);
            self.lastPageBeforeRotate = -1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That's the only solution that actually worked for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer for iOS 8+

Implement viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: in your controller.

Example:

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    NSUInteger visiblePage = (NSInteger) self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(visiblePage * self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is interesting that the scrollView.bounds uses the new/different value within the animateAlongsideTransition function.